# create text file with all folders in directory in order by date created

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have done a .bat file that opens notepad and fill it with a folders in the directory were the .bat file is placed.

Now I want to change it so that it will fill the text file with the folders in order by date of creation.

This is how my .bat files looks now:

```
dir /a /b /-p /o:gen >C:\WINDOWS\Temp\file_list.txt
start notepad C:\WINDOWS\Temp\file_list.txt
```

Also I would like an option to autosave the text file in the same directory.

Any help is higly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: From `dir /?` I would suppose `dir /o:dgen` should work

Answer (score 0):

This lists the folders and then the files, and saves the file in current folder.

```
dir /ad /tc /od /b >file_list.txt
dir /a-d /oen /b >>file_list.txt
start "" notepad file_list.txt
```